# LDAP connection over SSL doesn't work with parameter "com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.timeout"

Tags: java, ssl, ldap

I have faced the problem that my application couldn't connect to LDAP server via SSL (LDAPS://ldapserver:636). It was always throwing the exception :

```
2014-08-07 12:52:13,486 ERROR : simple bind failed: ldapserver:636
javax.naming.CommunicationException: simple bind failed: ldapserver:636 [Root exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake]
```

But after removed this line of code :

```
environments.put("com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.timeout", "10000");
```

It works. Can anyone explain that how the timeout property affects the LDAP SSL connection?

Thanks,
Stoper

Comment: Hmm. It shouldn't do that. The connection must have succeeded for there to be something for the server to close prematurely.

Answer (score -1):

SSL handshake needs some time to exchange the keys/certificates before establishing an SSL channel. You could increase the time out to 20 sec/20000 ms and check if this indeed is the problem.

Comment: True but this property is only supposed to control the *connect* timeout (and the connection pool if used), not read timeouts. There is a separate property for that.